# EventMachine RuntimeError in open_datagram_socket / open_udp_socket no datagram socket

Tags: ruby, sockets, udp, eventmachine

The following error appears when I try to `open_datagram_socket` on port `1900`:

```
/Users/timbaas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:859:in `open_udp_socket': no datagram socket (RuntimeError)
from /Users/timbaas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:859:in `open_datagram_socket'
from /Users/timbaas/Applications/ruby/upnp/ssdp.rb:36:in `block in initialize'
from /Users/timbaas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `call'
from /Users/timbaas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
from /Users/timbaas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
from /Users/timbaas/Applications/ruby/upnp/ssdp.rb:35:in `initialize'
from upnp.rb:4:in `new'
from upnp.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

I use the following code on Ruby 1.9.3:

```
module SSDP

  IP = "239.255.255.250"
  PORT = 1900

  class Server < EM::Connection
    def receive_data(data)
      p "d" + data
    end
  end

  class Socket
    attr_accessor :socket

    def initialize
      EventMachine::run do
        @socket = EM::open_datagram_socket SSDP::IP, SSDP::PORT, SSDP::Server
        p "Started EchoServer on #{SSDP::IP}:#{SSDP::PORT}..."
      end
    end
  end
end

Socket.new
```

When I use port `1901` it works..

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the port is not in use already?

Comment: I've looked up a lot of ways to see if that's the problem.. None of them points out that the address and/or port is in use.. I Don't know if I do it the right way though.. I've used: `lsof -i :1900` for example, which isn't showing anything..

Comment: Hmm, definitely not in use. Figured it was worth a shot though. For what it's worth, I'm able to run your code without getting any errors. The only thing I had to do is namespace `Socket.new` as `SSDP::Socket.new`

Comment: Hmm, I was afraid it's some permission issue.. But when I run `rvmsudo ruby upnp.rb` it's giving me the same error.. So couldn't be that right?

Comment: I'm not sure on that one. Is this part of a larger application or is this module the only thing you're running at the moment? Could there be any other code interfering?

Comment: As far as I know this is the only thing running.. Of course I've got some things like pow/mysql and more of that stuff running but none of my own projects.. Also restarted my Mac to be sure of this.. Only thing I know that could run on this port are some of the UPnP servers I tried lately like Twonky/EyeConnect..

Comment: @Beerlington So, I guess it was another process using this port.. I started killing processes from my activitymonitor and after killing some, I tried again, and it worked! Still need to find which process it was, but it works! Thanks for helping!

Comment: Interesting, glad you figured it out!